# Slicing two separate column groups in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following column names:

```
#housdata
RegionID    RegionName  State   Metro   CountyName  SizeRank    1996-04 1996-05 1996-06 1996-07 ... 2015-11 2015-12 2016-01
```

I want to slice from RegionID to CountyName, and from 2000-01 to end.

I have the following code which is wrong but I can't work out how to get the 2 groups.

```
housdata = housdata.loc[:, 'RegionID':'CountyName', '2000-01':]
```

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Coursera Michigan ? Completed couple of days back. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to create two data frames separately and merge them later.

```
   df1 = housdata.loc[:,'RegionID':'CountyName']
   df2 = housdata.loc[:,'2000-01':]

   df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing unnecessary dates

```
df = housing.copy() 
S= df.columns.get_loc("1996-04")
F= df.columns.get_loc("1999-12")
df.drop(df.iloc[:, S:(F+1)], inplace = True, axis = 1)
```

Remove unnecesary columns

```
df.drop(df.columns[[0, 3, 4, 5]], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_indexer` and `iloc`

```
a, b, c = df.columns.get_indexer(['RegionID','CountyName', '2000-01'])

df_slice = df.iloc[:, [*range(a, b+1)] + [*range(c, df.shape[1])]]
```